# Magento2: How to get Grand Total and Subtotal in the Observer

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer

Actually I have made observer as per Below

**XML Path:-**

```
app/code/Practice/Observer/etc/frontend/events.xml
```

**XML Code:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
       <observer name="checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Practice\Observer\Observer\Alert" />
   </event>
</config>
```

**Observer Path:-**

```
app/code/Practice/Observer/Observer/Alert.php
```

**Observer Code**:-

```
<?php

namespace Practice\Observer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Alert implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData();         
       print_r($item);
       exit();
}
}
```

It is working perfectly but i cannot get grandtotal using print_r function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try following code:**

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$item->getQuote()->collectTotals();
$subtotal = $item->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $item->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();

$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(array("Subtotal: ".$subtotal, "GrandTotal: ".$grandTotal));
```

Comment: I want to show result in print_r() or in echo like print_r($grandTotal); but it is not showing result why?

Comment: @Jaimin - Please check updated answer.

Comment: i already tried this but if i put die or exit then product cant add to cart so i cant see the result.

Comment: @Jaimin - You can check with log file, please try updated code.

Comment: Done :) @Pratik Oza

Comment: @Jaimin - Happy to help :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$item->getQuote()->collectTotals();
$quote = $item->getQuote();
$subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();

 \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')
                ->debug('subTotal', array('subTotal'=> $subTotal));
 \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')
                ->debug('grandTotal', array('grandTotal'=> $grandTotal));
```

**Note:** Check your result in var\log

Comment: Actually i want collection after add to cart but after putting your first code i cant add product to the cart @Abdul

Comment: Pls check ans updated and check your log

Comment: Do not use ObjectManager directly in module.